# How do i make the mouse flash every time i click with LUA?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I've tried using  `SetBacklightColor()` but looks like it doesn't work on my Logitech G203

Here's my code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
    SetBackLightColor(255, 255, 255)
     --Testing
    OutputLogMessage("a")
  end
end
```

Comment: AFAIK GHUB does not support controlling device illumination.  I did not see function `SetBackLightColor` in the GHUB documentation.

Comment: But you can write external program (exe file) working with Logitech LED illumination SDK functions, create a GHUB macro to run this exe-file, and invoke `PlayMacro` from Lua script to run this macro.

Comment: I found out i can use python to have access to the light, can i run python scripts with a macro?

Comment: Yes.  Create a macro invoking `pythonw.exe script.py`